# Auto refresh in swift

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection

I need to know how I could auto refresh the web page in Xcode using swift, I'm not asking for a pull to refresh or the refresh button, I have an app with my website on it(with two tabs on the button), but I need it to auto refresh when use visit one tab.

Something like this but in swift(this is in objective c):

```
-(void)get {
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/app.php"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(![responseString isEqualToString:@""]) {
    // reload
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this in Swift?  Objective-C and Swift can co-exist.
Take a look at: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/PRERELEASE/IOS/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH2-XID_0

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend studying tutorials with the UIRefreshControl.  Most are associated with animations, but you can ignore the animation part.

http://www.jackrabbitmobile.com/design/ios-custom-pull-to-refresh-control/